# Can scale be set when printing PDFs from mobile Safari to a Mac with Printopia?

Tags: macos, safari, pdf, printing

I'm on Mavericks 10.9.1, Safari 7.0.1. There are many occasions when I need to print PDFs to my networked printer remotely (i.e., From my iPad via Printopia) and they never print in the correct scale - always too large. I am using an HP DeskJet 3050 printer.

Please see the attached print dialogs - Safari and Preview. When I'm sitting at my laptop, I can use Preview and choose to scale properly. But Safari never scales properly, and even when I choose to have it scale, it doesn't do it right.

[image: Safari print dialog]
[image: Preview print dialog]

How can I have the iPad print at a set scale when printing remotely through Printopia?

Comment: I cleaned up some text - could you be more specific what exactly you want the correct printing to be? Your first step is to replicate the settings you are happy with on OS X and go into the Printopia control panel and set those preferences for Printopia to use.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't believe the issue is with Printopia at all. The dialog boxes above show what it looks like from Safari when I choose Print. As you can see, even though I have taken the time to go into the Paper Handling options and chosen Scale to Fit Paper Size, the thumbnail of the preview shows that the page content will not all fit. The other attached image shows, correctly, what it looks like in Preview. I only mentioned Printopia because I don't always print while at my laptop, otherwise I'd use Preview all the time.

Comment: So - Safari printing is what you want to solve? Scale to fit there seems to make no margins on the left/right and crop top/bottom?

Comment: If you see the two dialogs, the Safari thumbnail shows the page magnified such that the content is not sized to fit, so it gets cropped in all directions. With Preview, Scale to Fit correctly has all of the content showing, with a reasonable margin.